# SharePoint 2013 update fieldvalue

Tags: sharepoint

I have sharepoint list I have added a column "DistributionId" as a single line of text. I can see it in the fieldvalues when I debug. I can see it being set by the line listItem.FieldValues["DistributionId"] = "test";. However this is not updated in SharePoint and reverts to a blank value when the execute query is fired underneath. Also value is not set in SharePoint when checked directly. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(SpEndPointUri))
{
Site site = clientContext.Site;
Web web = clientContext.Web;

List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(library);

CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>" + documentId + @"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

// Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
clientContext.Load(items, ic => ic.Include(i => i, i => i["DisplayName"], i => i["Id"], i => i["HasUniqueRoleAssignments"]));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

ListItem listItem = items[0];

clientContext.Load(listItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

listItem.FieldValues["DistributionId"] = "test";

listItem.Update();

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

clientContext.Load(listItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ListItem.Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.item(v=office.15).aspx) to set field value instead. [ListItem.FieldValues property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.fieldvalues(v=office.15).aspx) is used *only for getting* a collection of key/value pairs containing the names and values for the fields of the list item.

How to update ListItem field value:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
listItem[fieldName] = fieldValue;
listItem.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: That works brilliantly. Thanks very much for taking the time to reply.